# terraform azurerm_managed_disk always replaced after terraform apply and destroy the VM

Tags: azure, terraform

As you can see below, I'm trying to deploy a new virtual machine using azurerm_managed_disk.
By the first time it works fine but every moment that I run terraform plan/apply the azurerm_managed_disk resource is rebuild that hence the VM that is using this disk is rebuild as well. Does anyone know what is happing ?

***Code:***

```
resource "azurerm_snapshot" "snapshot" {
  name                = "az1srzertosnaphot"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  create_option       = "Copy"
  source_resource_id  = data.azurerm_managed_disk.zerto_managed_disk.id
}

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "zerto_managed_disk" {
  name                 = "az1srzerto_managed_disk"
  location             = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option        = "Copy"
  source_resource_id   = azurerm_snapshot.snapshot.id
  disk_size_gb         = "127"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "zerto_virtual_machine" {
  name                  = var.vm_zerto_name
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  vm_size               = "Standard_D2s_v3"
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.vm_zerto_interface.id]
  

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = azurerm_managed_disk.zerto_managed_disk.name
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    disk_size_gb      = "127"
    os_type           = "Windows"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
    managed_disk_id   = azurerm_managed_disk.zerto_managed_disk.id
    create_option     = "Attach"
  }

  os_profile_windows_config {
    provision_vm_agent = false
```

***Follow the terraform plan***

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.disaster_recovery.azurerm_managed_disk.zerto_managed_disk must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "zerto_managed_disk" {
      ~ disk_iops_read_only           = 0 -> (known after apply)
      ~ disk_iops_read_write          = 500 -> (known after apply)
      ~ disk_mbps_read_only           = 0 -> (known after apply)
      ~ disk_mbps_read_write          = 60 -> (known after apply)
      - hyper_v_generation            = "V1" -> null # forces replacement
      ~ id                            = "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/az-prd-euw-disasterrecovery-rg-001/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/az1srzerto_managed_disk" -> (known after apply)
      + logical_sector_size           = (known after apply)
      ~ max_shares                    = 0 -> (known after apply)
        name                          = "az1srzerto_managed_disk"
      - on_demand_bursting_enabled    = false -> null
      - os_type                       = "Windows" -> null
      + source_uri                    = (known after apply)
      - tags                          = {} -> null
      + tier                          = (known after apply)
      - trusted_launch_enabled        = false -> null
        # (7 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

  # module.disaster_recovery.azurerm_virtual_machine.zerto_virtual_machine must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "zerto_virtual_machine" {
      + availability_set_id              = (known after apply)
      ~ id                               = "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/az-prd-euw-disasterrecovery-rg-001/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/az1srzerto" -> (known after apply)
      + license_type                     = (known after apply)
        name                             = "az1srzerto"
      - tags                             = {} -> null
      - zones                            = [] -> null
        # (6 unchanged attributes hidden)

      + identity {
          + identity_ids = (known after apply)
          + principal_id = (known after apply)
          + type         = (known after apply)
        }


      + storage_data_disk {
          + caching                   = (known after apply)
          + create_option             = (known after apply)
          + disk_size_gb              = (known after apply)
          + lun                       = (known after apply)
          + managed_disk_id           = (known after apply)
          + managed_disk_type         = (known after apply)
          + name                      = (known after apply)
          + vhd_uri                   = (known after apply)
          + write_accelerator_enabled = (known after apply)
        }

      + storage_image_reference {
          + id        = (known after apply)
          + offer     = (known after apply)
          + publisher = (known after apply)
          + sku       = (known after apply)
          + version   = (known after apply)
        }

      ~ storage_os_disk {
          ~ managed_disk_id           = "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/az-prd-euw-disasterrecovery-rg-001/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/az1srzerto_managed_disk" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
            name                      = "az1srzerto_managed_disk"
            # (6 unchanged attributes hidden)
        }
        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 2 to destroy.

──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────    

Note: You didn't use the -out option to save this plan, so Terraform can't guarantee to take exactly these actions if you run "terraform apply" now.
```

Any idea ?

Comment: This parameter is causing it to be recreated: `hyper_v_generation            = "V1" -> null # forces replacement`. Can you add that to the `azurerm_managed_disk` resource code block and try again?

Comment: Hello @fpsouza, Did the provided suggestion worked for you else share more details so that we can try to troubleshoot or else you can accept it as answer to help other community members for the similar issue ,so that they can find this and fix their problem. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

We have tried the same to create virtual machine using terraform with managed disk and snapshot.

As @*Marko E* suggested, ***We have also observed the same thing with different parameter (i.e,create_option= "Empty" and changed it to "copy")*** .

***ERROR DETAILS:-***
[image]

***AFTER CHANGING THE VALUE AS BEFORE***:-
[image]

The code that we are using is below.

***`main.tf`***:

```
provider   "azurerm"   { 
    features   {} 
 } 


variable "prefix" {
  default = "examplem"
}

locals {
  vm_name = "${var.prefix}-vm"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "${var.prefix}-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                  = local.vm_name
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_F2"

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "mydisk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = local.vm_name
    admin_username = "yourusername"
    admin_password = "yourpassword!"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }
}


resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "example" {
  name                 = "${local.vm_name}-disk1"
  location             = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  //source_resource_id   = azurerm_snapshot.example.id
  disk_size_gb         = 10
}

resource "azurerm_snapshot" "example" {
  name                = "snapshot"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  create_option       = "Copy"
  source_resource_id  = azurerm_managed_disk.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "example" {
  managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.example.id
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
  lun                = "10"
  caching            = "ReadWrite"
}
```

*Suggest you*, ***to resolve this issue, make sure that you have provided the same parameter with value as you have mentioned before on your managed disk.***

```
- hyper_v_generation            = "V1"
```

***SUCCESSFULLY APPLIED:-***

[image]

*For more information please refer this* **Blog by hashicorp**|[***Manages a Disk Snapshot***](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/snapshot).